# How can I update an item on Stream<List<Foo>> with Stream<Foo>?

Tags: flutter, dart, reactivex, rxdart

I have a list of 'Foo' and later got some periodic single Foo updates. Can I update the existing list?

Comment: Why do you have a `Stream<List<Foo>>` instead of `Stream<Foo>?`? What does the `List<T>` represent exactly?

Comment: @Dai The server first delivers a list, and then single updates from websocket.

Comment: Please post the definition of `Foo` and `UpdatedFoo`.

Comment: @Dai they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not a Flutter nor Dart user.

- I assume that your `Foo` and `UpdatedFoo` types have some kind of *primary key* member, such as `FooId`.
- I assume you're able to maintain an in-memory `Map<K,V>` of `Foo` instances by their `FooId` value.
- I assume you're *not* using the React, Redux, or Flux patterns.

Something like this:

```
class FooStore
{
    private Map<int,Foo> foos = new Map<int,Foo>();

    public void handleInitialFooStream( Stream<List<Foo>> initialStream ) async
    {
        // This `for` loop should only iterate once, btw.
        await for( List<Foo> fooList in initialStream )
        {
            this.setInitialFoos( fooList );
        }
    }

    private void setInitialFoos( List<Foo> initialFoos )
    {
        foreach( Foo foo in initialFoos )
        {
            this.foos[ foo.FooId ] = foo;
        }
    }

    public void handleFooStream( Stream<Foo> updateStream ) async
    {
        await for( Foo foo in updateStream )
        {
            this.foos[ foo.FooId ] = foo;
        }
    }
}
```